Is multiplication of finite partial orders cancellative? can we even prove the simplest case?
I was interested in whether taking the product of two finite partial orders is cancellative, i.e. whether $A \times C \cong B \times C$ implies $A \cong B$. I found that this was too difficult, so I instead worked on proving cancellativity for multiplication by a specific partial order $C$, and I found that $C=\{0,1\}$ (where $0 < 1$) is the simplest partial order for which cancellativity isn't trivial. I haven't managed to prove this either, but I think I've come close. My working is shown below. I would like to know whether cancellativity holds for all finite partial orders and how to prove it, and whether my proof for $C=\{0,1\}$ can be completed.
My working for $C=\{0,1\}$:
Define the set of immediate successors of $x$ in a partial order $X$ as the set of $z$ such that $x < z$, but there is no $y$ in $X$ such that $x < y < z$. In a product order, $X \times Y$, the immediate successors of $(x,y)$ are either $(x', y)$ where $x'$ is an immediate successor of $x$, or $(x, y')$ where $y'$ is an immediate successor of $y$. The immediate successors of an element are preserved by isomorphism.
Now consider $\{0,1\} \times X$. We consider $(0,x)$ to be paired to $(1,x)$ for any $x$. Suppose we have a pair $y_0,y_1 \in Y=\{0,1\}\times X$ with $y_0<y_1$. Then $y_0=(0,x)$ and $y_1=(1,x)$. The immediate successors of $(0,x)$ are all either $(0,x')$ for $x'$ an immediate successor of $x$, or $(1,x)$. Hence each immediate successor, $y_1'$, of $y_1$ is paired with an immediate successor of $y_0$, which is the unique immediate successor, $y_0'$, of $y_0$ such that $y_1'>y_0'$, other than $y_1$.
Let $\phi$ be an isomorphism $Y \to Y'$ with $Y'=\{0,1\} \times X'$ which preserves what $y_0$ is paired with. $\phi$ maps the set of immediate successors of $y_0$ to the set of immediate successors of $\phi(y_0)$, so it also preserves what each immediate successor of $y_0$ is paired with. This holds for any $y_0 \in Y$.
If $x < z$ then there is always a chain $x < y_1 < \dots < y_n < z$ of immediate successors, so $\phi$ must preserve pairings for every element $z>y_0$. By the same argument with the order reversed, $\phi$ must preserve pairings for every $z<y_0$. Hence $\phi$ preserves pairings for that entire connected component. So for connected partial orders, preserving any pair guarantees that an isomorphism preserves every pair.
If every pair is preserved, $\phi$ fixes the sub-order of $Y$ taking the lesser element from each pair, which must be isomorphic to $X$, or to $X'$ in the image. So $\phi$ restricts to an isomorphism $X \to X'$. Hence a single pairing being preserved guarantees $X \cong X'$ assuming connectedness.
Isomorphisms don't necessarily agree on any pair, for example, $\{0,1\} \times \{0,1\}^n$ (for $n \geq 1$) the identity automorphism and the automorphism that swaps the first and second coordinate disagree on what any element is paired with. But the only examples I can find of this are where $X$ is a product of $\{0,1\}$ and something else, which feels kind of like cheating, and it doesn't give an example of the product of partial orders not being commutative. Are there examples not of this form? I suspect it can be proved that these cheat examples are the only way to not preserve a single pairing. And if we get cancellativity for connected finite partial orders, we get it for all finite partial orders.
I intuitively think of this proof as saying that if we are given an axis to split the partial order along, we can extend that to the whole partial order and carry out the splitting. Examples like $\{0,1\} \times \{0,1\}^n$ don't work because there are multiple possible axes to split along.

Does this paper help?

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/269542/when-x-times-y-cong-x-times-z-implies-y-cong-z-in-the-category-of-finit/269545#269545

@Ulli thank you so much for finding that, that's a beautiful proof.

I have seen that argument before used to prove cancellation for finite groups, but did not realise that it works for so many finite (non-empty) structures: topological spaces, partially ordered sets, groups, modules over a ring, etc.  It even works for metric spaces (with $l_\infty$ norm on product, rather than the usual $l_2$).  Here we have to use distance non-increasing functions, as our maps.

I still don't know if my approach was workable, but there's a much simpler way, which @Ulli linked. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/269542/when-x-times-y-cong-x-times-z-implies-y-cong-z-in-the-category-of-finit/269545#269545 proves that multiplication of finite topological spaces is cancellative, and the finite partial orders are in one-to-one correspondence with the $T_0$ finite topologies (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandrov_topology) in a way that preserves products. So multiplication of finite partial orders is cancellative because it's equivalent to a multiplication of finite topological spaces. In fact, the same holds for preorders.
